# How can I make sed edit stream second time without piping it into itself?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a bash script that needs to continuously edit a monitor command, thus I can only use one pipe otherwise no output will be generated. I want sed to edit already edited stream but do it inside of one script

this command generates a bunch of information about wm

```sh
bspc subscribe report
```

output:

```
WMeDP-1:oI:OII:oIII:fIV:fV:fVI:fVII:oVIII:oIX:oX:LT:TT:G
WMeDP-1:oI:oII:oIII:fIV:FV:fVI:fVII:oVIII:oIX:oX:LT
WMeDP-1:oI:oII:oIII:fIV:fV:FVI:fVII:oVIII:oIX:oX:LT
WMeDP-1:oI:oII:oIII:fIV:fV:fVI:FVII:oVIII:oIX:oX:LT
```

this

```sh
bspc subscribe report | sed 's|:|\n|g'
```

works fine

output:

```
WMeDP-1
oI
OII
oIII
fIV
fV
fVI
fVII
oVIII
oIX
oX
LT
TT
G
...
```

but then i need to parse each line of newly generated stream, but piping like this is not an option

```sh
bspc subscribe report | sed 's|:|\n|g' | sed '|^O| {...} ...'
```

I've tried doing miltiple expressions

```sh
sed -e 'something' -e 'something'
```

I've tried using y instead of s

I've tried exchanging hold and pattern spaces but nothing worked

I'm fairly new to sed so im pretty sure there's something I've missed, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you inject newlines by a substitution, the pattern space will contain a multi-line expression (so an `O` at beginning of line will not necessarily match the regex `^O`). The trivial fix in this case is to switch the order of the commands in the script.

```
sed -e 's/\(^\|:\)O/{ ... stuff ... }' -e 'y/:/\n/'
```

Without more information about what's in `... stuff ...` it's not possible to specify in more detail whether this will work for you. Maybe your `... stuff ...` will require additional refactoring; or perhaps the simplest solution is really to run `sed` twice. Some `sed` versions have an `-u` or `--unbuffered` option which could help resolve the problem of running multiple scripts in an interactive pipeline.

Maybe the `sed` script could be refactored to loop over each field after the substitution; but again, without more detailed requirements, this is necessarily quite vague. Look at the `:` and `b` entries in the `sed` manual.

Finally, `sed` is a bit of a write-only language. Very often, you want to switch to a friendlier language like Awk for any non-trivial processing for improved readability and maintainability. The feature set and processing model is quite a bit more capable than `sed`'s, too.

Comment: thank you, --unbuffered actually solved it; ... stuff ... is just line formatting based on the first character btw

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple expressions for a single `sed` command by separating them with a semicolon (`;`)

The example that you've provided would look like this:

```
bspc subscribe report | sed 's|:|\n|g;|^O| {...} ...'
```

It can get a bit ugly if you need to use multiple complex expressions, though, but it gets the job done.

Comment: well, this does not wok either, like sed -e '...' -e '...'